# Java Web App : Linkage Error previously initiated > loading for a different type with name

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, tomcat, servlets

I was finally able to get my project to build, but it error-ed out when I tried to access the war. I am going by the Apress book *Pro Hibernate and MongoDB* by Anghel Leonard (found [here](http://www.apress.com/9781430257943)), but the example in the book will not produce any results.

pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>com.ogm</groupId>
    <artifactId>Maven_HOGM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.v201112011016</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <directory>c:\dev\Hibernate_OGM</directory>
        <defaultGoal>dependency:copy-dependencies</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/FileUpload</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I type

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

I get this error

> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: loader (instance of
>   org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) previously initiated loading
>   for a different type with name "javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest"
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:268)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) root
>   cause
>
> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance
>   of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) previously initiated
>   loading for a different type with name
>   "javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest"
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1845)
>     org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:226)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:148)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: I see you've asked more questions after this, does that mean you managed to solve this problem?  If so, how?

Comment: I ended up having to start the project over. I think it was just some way I set up the project initially.